# Вывод в Double или Float

Tags: c#, mysql, float, double

Пользователь вводит вероятность и сумму ставки (оба значения - натуральные числа).
Вывести выигрыш нужно как число с плавающей точкой, так же записать в базу данных число с плавающей точкой.

```
if (70 <= number2 && number2 < 80)
{
      if (value + 12 <= number2)
      {
            Win(value + 12, number2, Convert.ToDouble(number1 * (100 + 100 - number2) / 100));
      }
      else
      {
            if (value <= number2) Loose(value+12);
            else Loose(value);
      }
}

static void Win(int value, int number2, double win)
{
    string query1 = "UPDATE users SET balance = " + Convert.ToDouble(money - win) + " WHERE userid=" + userid;
    MySqlCommand comm1 = new MySqlCommand(query1, conn);
    comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (value <= number2)
    {
        vk.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams
        {
            ChatId = chat_id,
            Message = "Молодец, ты выиграл " + win + "! Число: " + value
        });
    }
    else
    {
        vk.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams
        {
            ChatId = chat_id,
            Message = "Молодец, ты выиграл " + win + "! Число: " + value
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чём состоит вопрос?

Comment: @VladD у меня сохраняется и выводится целое число, а нужно с плавающей точкой. Вот не знаю как сделать это.

Comment: Замечание: `float/double` нельзя использовать для подсчета денег. Используйте `decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, проблема в строке

```
Convert.ToDouble(number1 * (100 + 100 - number2) / 100)
```

Смотрите, что происходит: сначала выполняется целочисленное деление, и вычисляется целочисленный результат `number1 * (100 + 100 - number2) / 100`. Затем этот, уже округлённый до целого числа результат конвертируется в `double`. Но от этого у целого числа, понятно, не появится дробная часть.

Чтобы получить дробный результат, нужно проводить вычисления в дробных числах. Например, так:

```
Win(value + 12, number2, number1 * (100 + 100 - number2) / 100.0);
```

Comment: Всё то же целое число.

Comment: @FaridJannatov: А вы точно правильно скопировали выражение?

Comment: Да, точь в точь

Comment: @Farid: И чему равно значение переменной `win`?

Comment: Оно равно целому числу.

Comment: @FaridJannatov: (1) Какому числу? (2) А чему равны переменные `number1` и `number2`?